# Behat 2.4 upgrade issues, or Unrecognized options "extensions" under "behat" - error when attempting to activate sahi extension via behat.yml

Tags: behat, sahi, mink

Fairly new to this Behat stuff, and I've run into a roadblock I can't seem to get around. I've been staring at the docs, googling like it's my job, and doing my best to refrain from tossing my computer off the fire escape.

I'm working with a fairly complex project, and I'm not the one who set it up. So I'm a little lost in some areas.

Currently, I'm trying to use the Sahi driver, because selenium isn't cutting it for some dynamic forms I need to test. I can run the tests fine with the default selenium driver, but the tests fail because it doesn't adequately trigger JavaScript events on form input. Specifically, it'll work with the workarounds covered in that link, but only if I have the browser in focus. Which means it fails when the tests are run in sauce or via jenkins with xvfb.

I'm explaining all this only because this is my larger issue, which I'm attempting to address by using the Sahi driver. Which brings me to:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]  
Unrecognized options "extensions" under "behat"
```

That's what I get when I try to activate the Sahi driver for a particular profile in my bahat.yml the way the documentation says to.

Here's the default profile and the profile I'm currently working with in my behat.yml (slightly modifies for public consumption):

```
    default:
        paths:
            features: 'features'
            bootstrap: '%behat.paths.features%/bootstrap'

    sahi:
        extensions:
            Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
                 sahi:    ~
        context:
            class: 'FeatureContext'
            parameters:
                environment: 'staging'
                mink: 'sahi'
```

Fwiw, the tests are on a vm, which I ssh -X into, then run the test using

```
$ behat --tags @test_name_tag --profile=sahi
```

When I'm using the default selenium driver and the @javascript tag, the browser pops up and the tests run and pass (assuming I keep the browser in focus, of course).

I installed the additional drivers using composer:

```
    {
        "require": {
                "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
                "behat/mink": "1.4@stable",
                "behat/mink-extension": "*",
                "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
                "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*"
        }
    }
```

I've added `use Behat\Mink\Driver\SahiDriver;` to my MinkContext.php, EnvironmentContext.php and FeatureContext.php, though I'm guessing that's probably either overkill or not necessary. It doesn't seem to be making a difference at this point, though. I get the same error with or without it.

I also added a `sahi.php` which lives in features/bootstrap/mink:

```
    <?php

    return
    array(
        'default_session' => 'sahi',
        'sahi' => array(
            'capabilities' => array(
                'browserName' => 'firefox',
                'browserVersion' => 7,
            ),
        ),
    );
```

I thought maybe adding a directory in features/bootstrap called `exensions` might help for some reason. Even stuck a file in there called `sahi.php`. That didn't help much.

I think that covers everything. Thanks in advance for any help, and if this is covered elsewhere, please direct me to it, because I've spent countless hours looking and haven't found anything that helps me.

Update:

I uninstalled the old versions of behat, mink and gherkin, and installed 2.4, et al as per this https://lestbddphp.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/behatcomposer/

I've been making my way through "Migrating from Behat 2.3 to 2.4" in the docs. (Sorry, SO won't let me post any more links, but it's in the official Behat docs.)

My `composer.json`:

```
{
  "require": {
    "behat/behat": "2.4.*@stable",
    "behat/mink": "1.4@stable",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "*",
    "symfony/class-loader": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/form": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/validator": "2.1.*",
    "behat/mink-selenium-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-extension": "*",
    "behat/mink-sahi-driver": "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin/"
  }
}
```

I moved my `behat.yml` file to the root of the project, as directed. I updated my `default` profile to:

```
default:
    paths:
        features: 'features'
        bootstrap: '%behat.paths.features%/bootstrap'
    extensions:
      Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
        mink_driver: true
        kernel:
          env: test
          debug: true
      Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
        default_session: symfony2
        sahi:    ~
```

though I'm not entirely sure that's what I need. Just going by the example given in the docs.

I updated my `vendor/autoload.php` by replacing the `require_once` with `require`:

```
<?php

// autoload.php generated by Composer

require __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit::getLoader();
```

but I'm a little confused by this, because that file is different from the [example code in the docs](http://extensions.behat.org/symfony2/migrating_from_2.3_to_2.4.html#including-autoloader-from-composer). If I were to add the line in the docs here, instead of what was already there, then it would just be loading itself. (I tried. It barfed.) Am I completely dense, or is the wording here confusing/misleading? Did I do this correctly?

As I mentioned before, I have 3 context files in `features/bootstrap`:

```
FeatureContext.php
EnvironmentContext.php
MinkContext.php
```

When running the tests via cli, I pass it a `--profile`, and then it uses the appropriate profile in `behat.yml`. In almost all of the profiles, `FeatureContext` is used.

```
    context:
        class: 'FeatureContext'
```

`FeatureContext` then gets `EnvironmentContext` and `MinkContext`, from what I can tell. So, theoretically, everything should be working there.

Only it's not.

```
$  bin/behat --profile=sahi

  [ReflectionException]           
  Class AppKernel does not exist
```

Before I added all the Symfony stuff, I was getting this:

```
Warning: require(Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/project/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 112

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension' (include_path='/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/git core/templates/hooks:.') in /path/to/project/vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Extension/ExtensionManager.php on line 112
```

Which is why I added the Symfony stuff via composer.

Also possibly of note: when I forgot to pass it a --profile, before installing the Symfony stuff via composer, I got this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: environment in /home/lbaron/development/BeHat-Functional/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 43

Warning: include(/path/to/project/features/bootstrap/environment/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /path/to/project/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 44

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/path/to/project/features/bootstrap/environment/.php' for inclusion (include_path='/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/git-core/templates/hooks:.') in /path/to/project/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 44

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to EnvironmentContext::__construct() must be an array, boolean given, called in /path/to/project/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 44 and defined in /path/to/project/features/bootstrap/EnvironmentContext.php on line 27
```

Which I guess is to be expected.

So I'm at a loss now. Ideas?

I'm going to keep banging on it to see if I can figure it out, but any ideas/input would be greatly appreciated.

Update again:

Removing the extensions section from yml gives me this:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\History, array given, called in /usr/share/pear/mink/src/Behat/Mink/Behat/Context/MinkContext.php on line 163 and defined in /home/lbaron/development/BeHat-Functional/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php on line 52
```

Current state of behat.yml:

```
default:
    paths:
        features: 'features'
        bootstrap: '%behat.paths.features%/bootstrap'
    formatter:
        parameters:
            language: 'en'
    extensions:
      Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
          sahi: ~
          goutte: ~
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running a version of behat which is older that 2.4 (the current version). I can tell because the command you use is "behat" instead of "bin/behat". Older versions had a different architecture and did not use extensions. The documentation on the behat.org website is all for the new 2.4 version and, as far as I know, does not have the documentation for older versions available anymore. You should upgrade your behat version to 2.4, there is a guide on how to do this [here](http://extensions.behat.org/symfony2/migrating_from_2.3_to_2.4.html)

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I had a feeling it was something simple like that. Will do that and get back with results.

Comment: Upgraded, and now running into more issues. I updated my original post with details. Thanks.